# Вывод данных массива в две линии

Tags: php

Добрый день!

Есть массив, который каждый раз выдаёт разное количество данных, как чётное, так и не чётное количество (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9...).
Я циклом foreach прохожу весь массив. И мне его нужно вывести в 2 колонки div'ов. Т.е.

```
<div class="lines">
...Тут данные массива...
</div>
<div class="lines">
...Тут данные массива...
</div>
```

Проблема в том что у меня не получается закрыть вовремя основной блок .lines, сейчас я делаю так:

```
$max = count($group)+1; //4 2
        $center = floor($max/2); //2 1
        foreach ($group as $var)
        {
            if($count==1 OR $count == ($center+1)){$html.="<div class='lines'>";}
            $html.= "<div class='tehitem'>";

            $title = ($var=='') ? 'Прочие' : $var;

            $html.= "<h3>".$title."</h3>";
            $html.= " <ul class='reset tehinfo'> ";
            foreach ($arr_res as $prop) {
                if(in_array($var, $prop))
                {
                    $html.= "<li><span class='lbl'>{$prop['Name']} :</span> 
                        <span class='lbr'>{$prop['Value']}</span></li>"; 
                }
            }
            $html.= "</ul></div>";
            if($count==$center OR $count==$max){$html.="</div>";}
            $count++;
        }
```

Но у меня то закрывается, то не закрываются последний </div> и в итоге вся верстка рушится. Скажите пожалуйста как это сделать правильно, чтобы она всегда закрывалась?

Comment: А что если вы откроете условие до foreach те:
if($count==1 OR $count == ($center+1)){
foreach ($group as $var){
$html.="<div class='lines'>";
/////////////////////
$html.="</div>";
}

}
?

Comment: php выполняет скрипт сверху вниз, и если он однажды прошёл строку условия, он не вернётся к ней, следовательно условие, второй раз не будет проверятся, и он никогда больше не откроет мне второй lines.

Comment: Пример решения такой http://maxsite.org/page/formirovanie-kolonok-v-maxsite-cms , но пока разбираюсь как его внедрить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11);

$round = round(count($arr) / 2);

$disjoint = array_chunk($arr, $round);

//print_r($disjoint);

foreach($disjoint as $array)
{
    echo '<div class="lines">';

    foreach($array as $value)
    {
        echo $value;
    }

    echo '</div>';
}
```

Вроде все просто)

Comment: Идея не плохая, но у меня как вы заметили внутри ещё один цикл, и он на такую комбинацию не очень здраво реагирует.

Comment: Хотя нет, нормально выводит, но почему-то пока не решило проблемы. Верстка всё равно плывёт, ещё протестирую, может у меня всё правильно было.

Comment: Всё отлично! Спасибо большое!!! Я просто когда костыли делал, забыл убрать закрывашку)) сейчас всё отлично работает!)

Answer (score -1):

Условие открытия `div'a` -

```
if($count==1 OR $count == ($center+1))
```

Так сделайте таким же условие его закрытия,а то оно сейчас

```
if($count==$center OR $count==$max)
```

Comment: Вы не поняли вопроса. Если я сделаю открытие таким же как и закрытие, то у меня не получится сделать структуру DOM такой:
div.lines
- div.tehitem
- div.tehitem
div.lines
- div.tehitem
- div.tehitem

А получится так (если 4 данных в массиве)
<div.lines> ($count==1)
<div.tehitem></div.tehitem>
</div.lines> ($count==1)

<div.tehitem>
...
То есть tehitem не будет внутри lines, что рушит верстку не хуже чем тот вариант.